# How to draw 2 images with align by central?

Tags: html, css

My question is about HTML - I need to arrange 2 images (there are in same line) in central of line, but also I need to write text to the right of each image; text must be align on vertically rather image. How can I do it?

Comment: 2 images centered on each other, with text to the right vertically centered on the images?  If so, simply use a 2 column table with text align center on the image cell, and left align the text in the text cell, the text should auto vertically center.

Comment: Are both images the same width? Is this width static or does it change from page to page or display to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img1">
        <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Nature/Nature/Red%20Flower.png" />
        <span>This is flower1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
        <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Nature/Nature/Red%20Flower.png" />
        <span>This is flower2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS**:

```
div.container {
     margin: auto;
      width: 700px;  
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

div.img1 {
    position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
}

div.img2 {
    position: absolute;
     right: 0px;   
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I made this example for you [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4XtX/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In the old way, you can use a table with border=0 with 1 row and 4 cols. The table, and td tags allow you to align vertical and horizontal. This is a very simple way to achieve your requirements, but it's not probably the better.

Also, you can align working with divs.

Comment: Although there are a bunch of hacks and you can use javascript to do this, why use a hack just to get away from ta tables. They are the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: If you say it's not the better one yourself, then why suggest it? And answering "You can align working with divs" is kind of vague I think. I'm sure he can think of that himself, but he clearly does not know how to implement it.